# Hypothesis Testing of means

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Can anyone help me out with this question? My notes & textbooks just aren't giving me the explanations I need.

The average household size in a certain region several years ago was 3.14 persons. A sociologist wishes to test, at the 5% level of significance, whether it is decreased now. Preform the test using the information collected by the sociologist: in a random sample of 75 households, the average size was 2.98 persons, with a sample standard deviation 0.82 person.

1. State the null and the alternative hypotheses.

A. Ho: = 3.14 & Ha: < 3.14

B. Ho: = 3.14 & Ha: > 3.14

C. Ho: = 3.14 & Ha: ≠ 3.14

D. Ho: = 2.98 & Ha: ≠ 2.98

E. Ho: = 2.98 & Ha: > 2.98

I believe the answer would be B, but I am unsure if that's correct.

2. Compute the value of the test statistic.

A. -1.69

B. -2.73

C. 1.69

D. 2.73

E. -0.195

I tried using this formula, but I am not getting any of the above answers.
 
t= mean - standard deviation/ s/√n

I believe the answer is A. I plugged the numbers from the problem into the STAT-TESTS- Z-Int.

3. What is the rejection region?

A. (- infinity, -1.96]

B. [1.96, + infinity)

C. (- infinity, -1.64]

D. [1.64, + infinity)

E. (- infinity, -1.96] ∪ [1.96, + infinity)

I believe the answer would be A. because it is a left-tailed test since the test statistics is negative.

4. Based on the evidence can you make a decision for the sociologist.

I believe you do not reject Ho.

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag, read its [tag-wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) --- also see the information under 'Homework' in the [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 1):

1. This would actually be A since the alternative hypothesis is that the household size has decreased.
2. Test statistic = (observed-expected)/(standard deviation/sqrt(75). 
   This is (2.98-3.14)/(0.82/8.66) which = -1.69

check your parentheses with this calculation.

3. You have a left-tail test. The rejection region would be t less than or equal to the critical t value for your alpha level (5%). You can calculate the critical t values with free online calculators like this: http://www.mathcracker.com/t_critical_values.php

This website could be helpful for you to visualize left and right tail tests: https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat500/node/44

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't read the question thoroughly enough. It used the word decrease and lower in the question therefore they are looking to see if it was less. So I should be using the Ha: < 3.14